# How to decrease the utilization of my SSD drive as much as possible?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have a PC with a

- 250GB SSD &
- 500GB SATA HD.

I will have Linux root (/) in the SSD disk after the installation.

I want to minimize ssd utilization as much as possible.
Therefore, I will put the `/home` and `SWAP` on the SATA disk.
Is there anything else that I should put on SATA hard disk to decrease the utilization of SSD?

Answer (score 0):

`/var` and `/tmp` definitely go to HD from this perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I always smile on people that buys expensive SSD's and then configures system for anything else but performance. I hope you are informed that even if you put `/home` on your modern SSD, that drive will last for at least 10-12 years?
Common, be a man and put everything on your SSD! Mount your HDD as `/archive` for porn, and mount `/tmp` into RAM to boost performance even further. Get rid of swap partition as well! It's not needed if you have more than two gigs of RAM on Linux, and not going to use hibernate option (which is useless if your system boots in 10 seconds anyway, right?).

Comment: What about putting /run into ram as well?  I'm interested in your comment about removing the swap - I don't run SSD, but my swap seems completely unused as it is. I have 8 GB ram, but my boot time right now is about 45 seconds.

Comment: @CharlesGreen, `/run` is already mounted into RAM. This is a temporary file storage and has a special filesystem type called *tmpfs*, which is dynamically growing if needed, and by default can utilize up to 50% of computer RAM. It's usage can be observed via `df -h`. Btw, 45 seconds for Ubuntu is not bad (considering you are running a window manager, and booting from HDD). Have a look at average boot times for different Ubuntu versions and computer configurations, [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting).

Comment: Nah - I'm dual-booting rather than running the windows manager - it was much quicker in 13.10, and I've done something strange, but it may be that my partition does not align with physical sectors.  I'm planning on eventually getting to a single boot and running all windows in VMs, but I'm tired and slow.

Comment: RE /run - I didn't see /run mounted in fstab, so being a n00b I suumed that it was physically on the disk somewhere.  I had created a tmpfs for it, for a while, but saw no improvement in performance so reverted to default.  Thanks for the response!